# Why two F's back to back?

Tags: fringe

What is the reasoning behind the fringe logo design? Why two F's back to back? I'm watching the series on Netflix and wanted to know can across this page through Google search.

Comment: Read that but it still don't give the reasoning of the design it's self. Like the creators reasoning.

Comment: I suspect it's just a design thing. They wanted a cool logo for the Fringe division, to emphasise that it's been popularised. So they have a back-to-back F logo.

Comment: OK I had an ideal that it was two back to back F's to represent each Universe and the mirror opposite.  Just a thought. ..